# MySQL parameter not found in collection

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am stuck trying to update a MySQL value using parameters.
I think I can rule out typing errors.

I am getting the error "Parameter @inout_price not found in the collection".

Can anybody tell me where I went wrong?

```
   Using nCmdUp As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand = g_CnWebDB.CreateCommand
                    With nCmdUp
                        .CommandText = "UPDATE payinout SET inout_price=@inout_price WHERE inout_guid=@inout_guid"
                        Dim sNewPrice As String = "53.55"
                        .Parameters("@inout_price").Value = sNewPrice'In this line the error is thrown
                        .Parameters("@inout_guid").Value = sGUID
                        .ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End
                    End With

                End Using
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters should be added to the parameters collection.

```
 Using nCmdUp As MySqlCommand = g_CnWebDB.CreateCommand
     With nCmdUp
        .CommandText = "UPDATE payinout SET inout_price=@inout_price " & _
                       "WHERE inout_guid=@inout_guid"
        Dim sNewPrice As String = "53.55"
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@inout_price", sNewPrice)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@inout_guid", sGUID)
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
     End With
 End Using
```

You could use the shortcut [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (For Sql Server, but the concepts are the same) that adds the parameter and its value or use a more verbose way with [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The second approach is preferable if you want to fine tune your parameter datatype and size of varchar values.